# Compare a column of two data frames and replace the the value from a different in Dataframe to other dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes

*DF1 - {BranchID, ManagerJobcode, Managerlocation}*

*DF2 - {Managerjobcode, ManagerID}*

I need to match on the `DF1.ManagerJobcode` with `DF2.Managerjobcode`. If the value are equal, replace `DF1.ManagerJobcode` with `DF2.ManagerID`

Is it possible in single line of code in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's possible in a single line, but you could just join the 2 dataframes and then use `coalesce`.

here's how the code would look like

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, 'ManagerJobcode', 'left'). \
    withColumn('ManagerJobcode', func.coalesce('ManagerID', 'ManagerJobcode')). \
    drop('ManagerID')
```

Comment: This says "Joining multiple DataFrames only supported for joining on index"

Comment: This error looks like error from Pandas. Are you sure you are using pyspark DataFrame?

Comment: @Dhruv - are you using pandas dataframes or pyspark dataframes? check using `type(df1)` if you're unsure.

Comment: @samkart Thank you yes...i have corrected it..now i have both pyspark dataframes.. now getting the error .. " name 'func' is not defined " how do i import this ?cannot import name 'func' from 'pyspark.sql.functions' (/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py) Please suggest..

Comment: @Dhruv - added imports

Comment: Yes added the imports from pyspark.sql.functions import

Comment: Please let me know if any additional import statments needs to be added

Comment: @Dhruv - none for the aforementioned